# Reducing the size of the product of a matrix and a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, projection, projection-matrices

I have a matrix $P$ with size $(d,d)$ and two vectors $x$ and $y$ of size $(d,1)$.  I want to reduce the size of the quantity $(Px-Py)$ by setting the size of $P$ to be $(p,d)$ where $p \leq d$ to ensure that the scalar product $\|P^T (Px-Py)\|$ is as close as possible to the one when using the matrix with size $(d,d)$.

If this was about reducing the number of columns, I know that SVD can be used but the question here is about reducing the number of rows in $P$. Would it make sense to apply SVD decomposition to $P^T$ instead? In this sense, we will reduce the rows of $P$. Otherwise, is there a method that can be used to achieve this goal?

Comment: What is the scalar product between a matrix and a vector?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja: you are right. I modified the post. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: So you are looking for the (p,d) projection matrix $W$ such that $P \leftarrow W P$ and $$\| P^\intercal W^\intercal W P (x-y) \| \approx \| P^\intercal  P (x-y) \| $$

Comment: @JohnAlexiou: yes, you're correct in some sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but this seems related to Johnson-Lindenstrauss/subspace embedding. However, as stated, it it seems to be an underdetermined problem which you can solve with $p=1$ by simply taking some row vector $P = \alpha (x-y)^T$. Then $P^TP(x-y) = \alpha^2 (x-y) \|x-y\|^2$ and you can just set $\alpha = \|x-y\|$.